# As far away from London as my city is from it

Tags: sentence-construction, comparative-constructions

While talking about distance between cities I couldn’t understand how to use “as far away as” . This is why I needed to write to sentence to be corrected if I am wrong

> Your city is as far away from the London as my city is from it.

Or should I say

> Your city is as far away from the London as the distant between London and my city.

Comment: "Your city is as far (away) from London as my city is", or just "...as mine is." OR "Your city is the same distance from London as mine is." You don't need an article with the name of a place.

Comment: Your city is as far from London as mine.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use the word "the" with London.
Apart from that, the first example is correct, but longer than it needs to be. You could say

Your city is as far away from London as mine is.

Your second example is incorrect. You could correct it by saying
"The distance from your city to London is the same as the distance from my city to London.", but that's very wordy.